# How to print blinking text in python

Tags: python, text, blink

colorama is a package which is universal and will work independent of the platform. But it doesn't seem to support blinking text. Any other way this can be achieved in python ?

Comment: Doesn't this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533244/how-to-make-a-flashing-text-box-in-tkinter? There is also https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/08/09/wxpython-how-to-make-flashing-text/, and it seems you can do it with pygame too.

Comment: Thanks Ando ! Using wxpython or pygame , i have to install these on several PC's which run this code so becomes a dependency for which i don't have permissions.      The stackoverflow link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533244/how-to-make-a-flashing-text-box-in-tkinter provides info for flashing text box(opens a new one), but i have some text that is already getting printed and would like it to flash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
from termcolor import colored, cprint
cprint('\nJames Everleigh', 'red', attrs=['blink'])
```

cprint also allows bold, underlined, etc. and a small range of colors.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `\033[5m` in your print function:

```
print("\033[5mBlinking \033[0m Not Blinking")
```

`\033[0m` is used to reset, so to cancel the blinking, otherwise everything you write after `\033[5m` will be blinking.