# Making an image flash in python

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I am trying to flash an image using pack() and pack_forget().

We are building a custom BMW, and the lights are run with Raspberry Pi. I have the LED blinkers working using gpiozero, but now I need to show it on a display on the dash. I am able to hide and show the image using Label.pack_forget() and Label.pack() respectively in a function, but I cant get it to flash. I have tried the following code.

This works:

```
def showBG():
    background_label.pack()

def hideBG():
    background_label.pack_forget()

hideBttn = tk.Button(window, text="Hide Arrow", command = hideBG)
showBttn = tk.Button(window, text="Show Arrow", command = showBG)
```

This does not:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

def flashBG():
    for i in range(0, 3):
        background_label.pack()
        sleep(.7)
        background_label.pack_forget()
        sleep(.3)  

showHideBttn = tk.Button(window, text = "Flash Arrow", command = flashBG)
```

The first example shows and hides the Arrow as expected: Press the Hide Button and it disappears, press the Show Button and it appears.

The second example is supposed to flash 3 times like the blinker in your car on the dash. ON wait .7 secs, OFF wait .3 secs X3...

No errors, I click the Show Hide Button and the Arrow simply disappears when the for loop terminates.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `pack()` and `pack_forget()` to simulate flashing because the label may not be put in the same location if there are more than one widget in the same container.

Also, using `sleep()` will block the `mainloop()` from processing pending events which causes the `background_label` not being updated.

You should change the foreground color of the label to simulate flashing:

First save the foreground and background colors of the label after it is created:

```
flash_colors = (background_label.cget('bg'), background_label.cget('fg'))
# then flash_colors[0] is label background color
# and flash_colors[1] is label foreground color
```

Then modify `flashBG()` as below:

```
def flashBG(count=0, color_idx=0):
    # set label text color to background color (color_idx=0) to hide the label
    # or to foreground color (color_idx=1) to show the label
    background_label.config(fg=flash_colors[color_idx])
    if count < 5:
        # execute flashBG() again after 300ms or 700ms based on the color of the label
        window.after(300 if color_idx==0 else 700, flashBG, count+1, 1-color_idx)
```

`flashBG(...)` will be executed 6 times (OFF 3 times, ON 3 times).

Comment: Great to know that sleep terminates mainloop. I did not know. Indeed I have very little understanding of how python processes.Thank you so much for that. I am pretty new to Python and only barely know a couple packages. I don't fully understand the code you forwarded above, but I will copy it and see what I can learn. In the mean time do you have time to comment the code so I can know whats happening?

Comment: @KenS comments added.

Comment: Thanks so much, that helps a lot!

Comment: I am still struggling with this issue. I am sure this is a simple task, but as I am very new to python, I cant get this to happen. I decided it would be better to change the fill of a shape. I just don't know hoe to access the fill property to change it when I click a button.Here is what I have:
```

Answer (score 1):

see [How to make a flashing text box in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533244/how-to-make-a-flashing-text-box-in-tkinter)

The for loop will execute in its entirety before the effect is made on the tkinter widget. Since the last thing it does is pack_forget(), nothing appears

Comment: OK,  that's great to know! Will you please tell me how to accomplish my goal? I tried removing the for loop and simply repeating the block of commands 3 times.