# Making a flashing text in tinker

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want a text that flashes with a clock's seconds. This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533244/how-to-make-a-flashing-text-box-in-tkinter) was helpful, but couldn't solve my problem. Below is my little working code:

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import time

def change_color():
    curtime=''
    newtime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    if newtime != curtime:
        curtime =  dt.date.today().strftime("%B")[:3]+", "+dt.datetime.now().strftime("%d")+"\n"+newtime
        clock.config(text=curtime)
    clock.after(200, change_color)

    flash_colours=('black', 'red')
    for i in range(0, len(flash_colours)):
       print("{0}".format(flash_colours[i]))
       flashing_text.config(foreground="{0}".format(flash_colours[i]))

root = Tk()
clock = Label(root, text="clock")
clock.pack()
flashing_text = Label(root, text="Flashing text")
flashing_text.pack()
change_color()
root.mainloop()
```

This line of code: `print("{0}".format(flash_colours[i]))` prints the alternating colors on the console as the function calls itself every 200s. But the flashing_text Label's text foreground doesn't change colors.

Does anybody have a solution to this problem? Thanks!

Please forgive my bad coding.

Comment: Thanks soo much for the editing, @BossElijah

Comment: No problem! @Anas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have changed the color of the `flashing_text` in the for loop twice, but the tkinter event handler (`mainloop()`) can only process the changes when it takes back the control after `change_color()` completed.  So you can only see the `flashing_text` in red (the last color change).

To achieve the goal, you need to change the color once in the `change_color()`.  Below is a modified `change_color()`:

```
def change_color(color_idx=0, pasttime=None):
    newtime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    if newtime != pasttime:
        curtime =  dt.date.today().strftime("%B")[:3]+", "+dt.datetime.now().strftime("%d")+"\n"+newtime
        clock.config(text=curtime)
    flash_colors = ('black', 'red')
    flashing_text.config(foreground=flash_colors[color_idx])
    clock.after(200, change_color, 1-color_idx, newtime)
```

Comment: Oh acw1668, though your answer came late, I have tried it and it worked. For sure I can boost of two ways of achieving a flashing text, your code and that of @Axe319's.

Answer (score 0):

I would add it to a class so you can share your variables from each callback.

So something like this.

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
import time

class Clock:
    def __init__(self, colors):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.clock = Label(self.root, text="clock")
        self.clock.pack()
        self.flashing_text = Label(self.root, text="Flashing text")
        self.flashing_text.pack()
        self.curtime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        self.flash_colours = colors
        self.current_colour = 0

        self.change_color()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def change_color(self):
        self.newtime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        if self.newtime != self.curtime:
            if not self.current_colour:
                self.current_colour = 1
            else:
                self.current_colour = 0

            self.curtime = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            self.flashing_text.config(foreground="{0}".format(self.flash_colours[self.current_colour]))
            self.clock.config(text=self.curtime)

        self.clock.after(200, self.change_color)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clock = Clock(('black', 'red'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Axe319, your solution worked for me perfectly as I wanted. Your code brought to my realization  improper initialization of 'self.current_colour', so it kept repeating the second colour (red).