# Trying to create a red-translucent , flashing gui with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

parent = Tk()
parent.geometry('500x500')
parent.title('Test in progress...')
parent.attributes('-alpha',0.5)
#parent.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
button1 = Button(parent, text = 'FOUND!',fg='red', command=parent.destroy)
button1.pack()
parent.mainloop()
```

I want this to flash translucent-red on fullscreen without effecting the user abilty to select things.

Comment: You've explained what you're building, but haven't asked a question. What specific part of the problem do you need help with. The code presented doesn't even seem to attempt to flash. Is that what you're asking how to do? Are you aware of the `after` method that can be used to schedule function calls on an interval?

Comment: Sorry about that, the flashing and making it red-translucent and not just translucent, is the problem I'm having.

Comment: Stackoverflow works best when you ask about only one problem at a time.

Comment: Thank you @BryanOakley, this is my first time using this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27533244/how-to-make-a-flashing-text-box-in-tkinter) I think I have something to help you.  You need to have a function that will control the changes to color utilizing `.after`. It shifts from white transparent to red in a "flashing" like manner. I hope this is in the ballpark for what you want.

```
from tkinter import *


def change_color():
    current_color = parent.cget("bg")
    next_color = "white" if current_color == "red" else "red"
    parent.config(background=next_color)
    parent.after(1000, change_color)


parent = Tk()
parent.config(bg="red")
parent.attributes('-alpha', 0.5)
parent.geometry('500x500')
parent.title('Test in progress...')


button1 = Button(parent, text='FOUND!', fg='red', command=parent.destroy)
button1.pack()

change_color()
parent.mainloop()
```